# Web API - Render PDF in browser as response of GET

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

We have a web api GET method which should return a PDF file as output. Also, when i try the GET method from a browser window, it should render the PDF in the browser window. Is there any way we can accomplish this?

Regards,

Lolek

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return a PDF from a Web API application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042614/how-to-return-a-pdf-from-a-web-api-application)

Comment: I answered a question about returning a PDF from web API which might help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210055/how-to-pass-a-pdf-from-webapi-and-read-the-pdf-from-the-mvc-controller/43232581#43232581